# Odoo mail.template foreign key constraint error

Tags: odoo-12

Im trying to add an email template to my custom module, When I add the email template like below I get an error.
`odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "insert or update on table "mail_template" violates foreign key constraint "mail_template_model_id_fkey"`
The only way I can get the template installed to odoo is by removing the model_id field.
Ways Ive tried model_id: it_onboarding.it_onboarding ,it_onboarding.model_it_onboarding, model_it_onboarding, it_onboarding. All of those variations on the model name give External ID errors except it_onboarding.it_onboarding which give the foreign key constraint error.

Module name: it_onboarding.it_onboarding

Filename: data/it_request_approval_email.xml

Email Template:

```
<record id="it_request_email_template" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">New IT Request ${object.reference}</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="it_onboarding.it_onboarding"/>
            <field name="subject">${object.reference} needs approval</field>
            <field name="email_from">dummy@mail.com</field>
            <field name="email_to">dummy@mail.com</field>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="False"/>
            <field name="user_signature" eval="False"/>
            <field name="body_html" type="html">
                <div>
                    ${object.reference} has been received and needs approval
                </div>
            </field>
```

Grateful for any ideas

### File Structure

```
-it_onboarding
--controllers
--data
 --it_request_approval_email.xml
 --sequence.xml
--models
--reports
--security
--static
--views
--__init__.py
--__manifest__.py
```

### Manifest

```
"data": [
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'security/security.xml',
        'data/sequence.xml',
        'views/views.xml',
        'views/templates.xml',
        'views/it_user_view.xml',
        'reports/it_user_report.xml',
        'reports/it_request_report.xml',
        'reports/approval_email_report.xml',
        'data/it_request_approval_email.xml',

    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this variation and if possible please provide a snip or link of your folder structure:

```
<field name="model_id" ref="folder_name.model_class_name"/>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Ive tried that. if I us anything other than it_onboarding.it_onboarding I get "External ID not found in the system. when I use it_onboarding.it_onboarding the error I get is . `odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "insert or update on table "mail_template" violates foreign key constraint "mail_template_model_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (model_id)=(515) is not present in table "ir_model".
" while parsing /home/maccer/Documents/Projects/PycharmProjects/Odoo12/custom_addons/it_onboarding/data/it_request_approval_email.xml:7, near `
it_onboarding

Comment: Ive had a look in the ir.model table and (model_id)=(515) does not exist. the id for the model I want is 1135

Comment: then check the name of the model in pgadmin where it_model.id = 1135

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue. I was formatting the `model_id` incorrectly.

- **Model name:** `it_onboarding.it_onboarding`
- **`model_id`:** `model_it_onboarding_it_onboarding`